# Splitting an Access Database into back and front end issues

Tags: ms-access, split, vba

I have been trying to split my access database into a front and back end wiht no avail... I keep getting an error that says "The database engine could not lock table "" because it is already in use by another person or process". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried manually splitting your DB?

Comment: I have submitted an answer

Answer (score 0):

to manually split your DB. you can do the following:

Copy your database in to the location of the back end. Delete all forms, queries and reports. Just leaving the tables.

Then in what will become your front end  go to External Data>Access and import those tables from your backend. ensure that you click on the "Link to the data source by creating linked tables".

Let me know if it works. you should see that the tables(navigation pane) in the frontend now have a little arrow next to them.